# Control layer order in geojson layers (multiple layers in a variable)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have multiple frog habitat layers that I want to show on my map of central america, so I have added them to a variable that stores the local geojson data like so:

```
var frogs = [blackEyed, yellowEyed, lemurLeaf, splendidLeaf, redEyed];
```

I then want to specify 'redEyed' frog as the bottom layer as it has the largest extent, so at the moment it is covering the other layers and making them unable to be hovered over. What would be the simplest way to do this?

I have tried using a turf.featureCollection() to group the layers but I am unsure how to specify the drawing order without calling each layer separately as currently I am adding them to the map using:

```
geojson = L.geoJson(frogs, { 
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: setEvents,   
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: What library you are using?(name it in the tag list). what you have tried and did not work?

Comment: Sorry I am using leaflet and turf.js and I have tried a var frogs = turf.featureCollection([blackEyed, yellowEyed, lemurLeaf, splendidLeaf, redEyed]); which then loses my dynamic layer styling I used by using getColour(feature), and I have tried bringTofront(), but it seems to be working on the whole array, not each individual feature class.